# Monitorar Diretório com Java Web

Tags: java, java-ee

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação *Java* Web, utilizando o servidor *Apache Tomcat* e tenho a necessidade de monitorar, ou "ouvir" um diretório no servidor. De forma assíncrona, e permanente. Pois quando um arquivo for criado neste diretório, eu preciso examinar e mover o mesmo para o diretório correto.

Eu até consegui utilizar o [Watch Service API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html), porém consegui funcionar somente para uma aplicação java local (jar).

Há possibilidade de utilizar para web? Ou existe alguma outra maneira mais eficaz?

Comment: não sei o seu caso mas eu estou tendo problemas quando inicio o watch preciso fazer alterações no visual e isso não acontece até mesmo minha aplicação swing não fecha depois de ativo. Estou procurando uma solução mas sem sucesso.

Comment: @DevAgil consegue postar melhores detalhes do problema ou do código mesmo?

Comment: Segue o link da minha duvida http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116281/monitoramento-de-diret%C3%B3rio-faz-o-sistema-parar-de-responder-a-intera%C3%A7%C3%B5es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Atenção com a versão do Java**

Sim, pode utilizar para aplicação Web Sim, sem problemas, até mesmo por que está na plataforma Java SE. Só se atente par ao fato da versão Java, vc deve usar no mínimo a versão 1.7 da plataforma. Então cheque se o servidor Web ou EE está de acrodo com essa versão do Java. Dependendo da versão do Tomcat, pode ser que vc não consiga usar.

O Watch Service é muito poderoso, deve te atender perfeitamente.

Comment: Legal @FilipeGonzagaMiranda, e como eu posso deixar ela executando permanentemente após o deploy? Necessito do uso de threads?

Comment: Ai depende muito do design da sua aplicação, realmente é difícil eu te dizer a frio. Por exemplo, eu não sei se vc estará usando EJBs, outros frameworks. Em fim, o que eu recomendaria é vc Startar o serviço no Init do seu Servlet Mapeado no Web.xml, colocando um Thread lá, mas novamente, é muito difícil dizer sem ter todos os detalhes em mão. E é claro podem surgir diferentes soluções e abordagens. Eu começaria pensando no init do Servlet

Comment: Acredito que o Init do Servlet ajuda, é uma aplicação web (servlet) simples mesmo, apenas com o objetivo de monitorar um diretório, analisar os arquivos e mover para os diretório destino. Nada de EJB ou outros frameworks. Obrigado