# Monitoramento de diretório faz o sistema parar de responder a interações

Tags: java, arquivo, watch

Tenho uma aplicação que monitora uma certa pasta e verifica se  existe a criação de um novo arquivo se um novo arquivo é criado disparo vários processos no sistema.

Mas quando ativo o monitoramento parece ele trava vários processos e não me permite quase que nenhuma interação com o meu sistema.

```
public void Monitoramento(){

    Path pastaOrigem;
    try {
        pastaOrigem = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("C:\\monitoramento"));


    watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();


    pastaOrigem.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);

    while (true) {

        WatchKey wk = null;
        try {

            wk = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {

            if (event.kind() == OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }

            WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
            Path nomeArquivo = ev.context();
            Path arquivoOrigem = pastaOrigem.resolve(nomeArquivo);

            String arquivo = nomeArquivo.toString();

            if (arquivo.substring(0, 3).equals("vn")) {


               novoEvento ne = new novoEvento();


               ne.leituraArquivo(arquivoOrigem);

            }

        }

        if (!wk.reset()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TelaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: tem uma pergunta parecida porém não se trata do mesmo assunto.

Comment: Seria uma boa ideia colocar algumas informações sobre o sistema hospedeiro.

Comment: Cara, conferindo com meu código que fiz aqui, notei apenas uma diferença. Ali no final você verifica se a chave foi resetada e da um break. Eu verifico se a chave foi resetada, caso contrario, faço um Keys.remove(wk), ai verifico se a wk.isEmpty, para ai sim dar o break.